# Are virtual method not "delete"able in C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual

The error message seems to be little mis-leading with the scenario, when we try to `delete` a `virtual` method.

```
prog.cpp:4:16: error: deleted function 'virtual void Test::foo()'
prog.cpp:8:2: error: used here
```

Code

```
struct Test : public Base
{
  Test() {}
  virtual void foo () = delete;  // error
};
```

Are `virtual` method not `delete`able for the same reason, why they cannot remain unimplemented in C++03 ? Is there any way to mention that `Test` purposely not implementing `virtual foo()` ?

Comment: Try just mention them as virtual without the deletetion.

Comment: Wow I had till now never realized that you could do this. And secondly is it by any ways helpful or usable ?

Comment: @DumbCoder: Well, you can't. You get an error. Hence this question.

Comment: If we should be allowed to call `(Base*)->foo()`, and `Base*` could be a `Test*`, then how could we allow `Test` not to either implement `foo` or be abstract? How would it make sense to _remove_ a function from a derived class that has to exist?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I was more wondering about how helpful it is and where would you use it ? Should have made it explicit. Probably will go and have a look at the standard docus.

Comment: It makes no sense. The public inheritance means *is-a*, it's a fundamental requirement that derived class implements (possibly overrides) complete virtual interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term *use* has a concrete definition in the standard, and in particular for virtual functions the definition of *odr-used* is:

> §3.2/2 (C++0x FDIS) [...]A virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure.[...]

Where *odr-used* is a new term in the upcoming standard that refers to what the previous standard called plainly *used*:

> §3.2/2 (current standard) [...]A virtual member function is used if it is not pure.[...]

My take is that the error message employs the term *used* to refer to *odr-used* in this particular case, and yes, the reason why this is a violation is exactly the same reason by which you cannot leave a non-pure virtual member function unimplemented.

Comment: Then, does it make sense to be able to specify both `delete` and `virtual` for the same function ? It seems to me that either one should "win", and it does not seem to be sensible for `delete` to win...

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I guess that the standard could explicitly state that `delete` cannot be used with a `virtual` method, but then again, it does *say* so through the whole set of rules... The compiler should be able to warn you that that particular combination will never work, and probably in the future they will, as of now you get a *slightly* cryptic error

Comment: I'll test this on CLang, hopefully the diagnosis is more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

All non-pure virtual functions must be implemented, [whether you use them or not](http://www.ideone.com/ktnYv):

```
struct Test
{
  Test() {}
  virtual void foo();
};

int main() {
   Test* t = new Test;
   // ^ it seems to have to be dynamic allocation to coerce the error out
}

/* Output:
/home/Y3oGMf/ccOLuYWf.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for Test'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*/
```

I think you're seeing the slightly odd error message regarding *use* of a deleted function for a similar reason. It's just because of how things work internally. A more sensible error message might be on the line where you attempted to `delete` a `virtual` function member, saying "this is not going to work. it's going to cause problems because this implementation *must* exist."

It doesn't make sense to `delete` an interface function anyway. Inheritance adds functionality; it does not take it away. Notice how making a member function *pure* virtual prohibits the entire class from being instantiated: derived classes must re-implement the functionality so that it is not lost.

Comment: You have it another corner case. This one is a compiler bug... but it's scary stuff unfortunately. The problem is: *into which object file should the vtable and typeinfo be emitted* ? C++ does not require a single .cpp file to implement the whole class. gcc takes the rule that the `vtable` and `typeinfo` are emitted in the same object file as the first non-inline function of the class (here `foo` since the constructor is inline), and failing to define this function results in this strange linker error... See http://www.ideone.com/rEp41 (just add another non-inline method before `foo`)

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't understand why this is a corner case or a compiler bug. The rationale you wrote sounds completely plausible and _normal_ to me.

Comment: the standard does not specify when to emit the information, we could argue that a conforming compiler should always emit it, regardless of the presence of other "errors". The error message is certainly confusing the first time you get it! But from the Standard point of view, the program stops making sense at the first error, so the discussion is moot.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is delete keyword is for deleting default implementation that is generated by compiler. For virtual methods there is no default implementation generated by compiler.

Comment: For default implementation, we have `= default` keyword. `= delete` is to disallow referring the member.

Comment: `delete` can be used to delete the default implementation and to forbid specific members (which is actually the same thing).

Comment: @iammilind: Indeed, `delete` **disallows** something. But you cannot disallow something in the derived class which the base class promises to exist in all its derived classes, non?

Answer (score 2):

Deleted virtual functions are allowed, but overriding them is not.

§10.3(11) says:

> **A virtual function** declared in a class **shall be defined**, or declared pure (10.4) in that class, or both; but no diagnostic is required (3.2).

§8.4.1 says that **a deleted function is defined**.

And §10.3(16) says:

> A function with a deleted definition (8.4) shall not override a function that does not have a deleted definition. Likewise, a function that does not have a deleted definition shall not override a function with a deleted definition.

The intention of this last rule is to ensure that a call to a deleted function can be diagnosed at compile time.

So the following code is ill formed:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo();
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual void foo() = delete;
};
```

But the following code is well formed:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = delete;
};
struct Derived : public Base {
    virtual void foo() = delete;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/m0sVQa)

OP had either a compiler bug or QoI issue (it's hard to tell which because he didn't post the whole code) which has since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not derive from a class that REQUIRES something if your derived class cannot implement it. Probably you don't need to derive from that class in the first place.

It's like saying "I'm building a better car. Which is kind of a car but does not implement wheels." Are you sure that it is a car then in the first place?

Or are you asking this just out of curiosity?

Comment: Should this have been a comment?